# Python Regex - Summing the total of times strings from a list appear in a separate string

Tags: python, regex, text, count, python-re

Regex and text data noob here.

I have a list of terms and I want to get a single sum of the total
times the strings from my list appear in a separate string.  In the example below, the letter "o" appears 3 times in my string and the letter "b" appears 2 times. I've created a variable called allcount which I know doesn't work, but ideally would have a total sum of 5.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import re
mylist = ['o', 'b']
my_string = 'Bob is cool'
onecount = len(re.findall('o', my_string)) #this works

#allcount = sum(len(re.findall(mylist, my_string))) #this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and iterating over the list elements would be easier and more efficient:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(my_string.lower())
# Counter({'b': 2, 'o': 3, ' ': 2, 'i': 1, 's': 1, 'c': 1, 'l': 1})
[c[s] for s in mylist]
# [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find different patterns in your string.

This can be done by using pipe **|** sign

```
import re

mylist = ['o', 'b']
my_string = 'Bob is cool'
onecount = len(re.findall("o|b|B", my_string)) #this works

print(onecount)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to import additional libraries, nor to use a regular expression.

Considering that `mylist` and `my_string` look as follows

```
mylist = ['o', 'B']
my_string = 'Bob is cool'
```

Assuming the goal is to obtain a list with the count in the same order that the strings appear in the list `mylist`, one can do the following

```
newlist = [my_string.lower().count(x.lower()) for x in mylist]

[Out]: [3, 2]
```

If, on another hand, the goal is to obtain a dictionary where the keys are the strings from `mylist` and the values are the number of times they appear in `my_string`, one can do the following

```
newdict = {x.lower():my_string.lower().count(x.lower()) for x in mylist}

[Out]: {'b': 2, 'o': 3}
```

---

**Notes:**

- The `.lower()` is to make it case insensitive.